# Derby SQL style stored procedure support

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, derby

Does Derby support SQL style stored procedures?

Based on the following wiki page: https://wiki.apache.org/db-derby/DerbySQLroutines, Derby indeed supports stored procedure defined as Java code, but nowhere does it implies that SQL style stored procedure are not supported.

I tried the following valid SQL construct

```
CREATE PROCEDURE getValues AS select * from tableName
```

but received the following error:

```
Syntax error: Encountered "AS" at line 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that Apache Derby does not support SQL style stored procedures.

There was a thread discussing adding support for this feature, with no resolution: http://apache-database.10148.n7.nabble.com/Regarding-Derby-Stored-Procedures-td82610.html